# Kendoui Template Error

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

getting a Uncaught Error: Invalid template: from this kendoui template.  What am i missing here?

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="listviewProxiesTemplate">
   <div data-mrn=${Mrn}><label>${DisplayText}<input name="account" type="radio"  #if(# ${IsActive} # =='true'){# checked="checked" #}# /></label></div>
</script>
```

I want to set the radio button to checked if the Json objects IsActive property is true....

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 2):

Looks like i was escaping the IsActive property and i didn't need to.  This updated template is working for me.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="listviewProxiesTemplate">
   <div data-mrn=${Mrn}><label>${DisplayText}<input name="account" type="radio"  #if(IsActive){# checked="checked" #}# /></label></div>
</script>
```

Comment: That's right! In addition, did you realize that being radio buttons and all with the same `name` only one can be active no matter what you receive? Is that what you want? Otherwise use different `name` for each `radio` input.

Comment: Yeap i wanted this selection to be mutually exclusive, but good point.